Doing a SELECT * FROM TABLE gives "Cannot read field of type FLOAT64 as STRING Field"
There is an error in SELECT statement with WHERE condition. "Cannot read field of type FLOAT64 as STRING Field". I verified schema and field type is STRING, not sure why it recognize it as FLOAT64.
Query
SELECT * FROM `TABLE_2*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '0240303' AND '0240304'
AND jsonPayload.property1 LIKE '%text-text%'
AND jsonPayload.property2 LIKE '%/text'

Output into results tab

Cannot read field of type FLOAT64 as STRING Field: jsonPayload.node.property

I tried to ran a SELECT statement with WHERE condition but I got an error. I expect to get query results.

The query is reading several tables as indicated by the asterix TABLE_2*. In one table at least one column is string and in the other table this column is Float64. Lets call this column colA, then use SELECT * except(colA) FROM. If this column is needed all tables need to be listed with UNION ALL SELECT, then CAST(colA as string) can solve this issue.

Building on Samuel's suggestion, utilizing the CAST function can provide an effective solution for your use case. To implement this, identify the specific field causing the data type mismatch and then cast it to a string format. This will resolve the error you're encountering.
These additional resources can provide further insights into the topic.

ACCEPTED: Bigquery - How to cast float to string w/o round up/down?

CAST AS STRING

Conversion rules


In my research, I discovered a similar post that appears to be related to a bug. To ensure we're addressing the root cause, I checked our issue tracker for any open or ongoing issues related to your specific use case and found none. If you suspect this might be a bug, please don't hesitate to submit a ticket in our issue tracker for further investigation.
